# Find Last, Min Values using Case Statement

Tags: sql, case, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to find out several values:

1. orl_adnr_amt When orl_stage_phase_nm = Closed (should be 1900)
2. Minimum orl_adnr_amt When orl_stage_phase_nm <> Closed (should be 1500)
3. Maximum orl_adnr_amt When orl_stage_phase_nm <> Closed (should be 1900)

This is my query:

```
Select
A.oprty_key_nbr,
B.Closed_Won_ADNR,
B.OPEN_Phase_MIN_ADNR,
B.OPEN_Phase_MAX_ADNR,
A.#Changed_ADNR_Amts

            from(select distinct
            A.oprty_key_nbr,
            count (distinct A.orl_adnr_amt) as #Changed_ADNR_Amts

            from isell_prod_view_db.sfdc_opportunity_lifecycle A
            where A.oprty_key_nbr = '983yhjheksi9ru8jdl'
            and A.orl_adnr_amt is not null

            group by 1 ) A
            
            left join (Select distinct
                B.oprty_key_nbr,
                B.orl_adnr_amt,
                B.orl_stage_phase_nm,
                CASE WHEN B.orl_stage_phase_nm = 'Closed - Won' THEN B.orl_adnr_amt else '' end AS Closed_Won_ADNR,
                CASE WHEN B.orl_stage_phase_nm <> 'Closed - Won'THEN MIN(B.orl_adnr_amt) else '' end AS OPEN_Phase_MIN_ADNR,
                CASE WHEN B.orl_stage_phase_nm <> 'Closed - Won'THEN MAX(B.orl_adnr_amt) else '' end AS OPEN_Phase_MAX_ADNR

            from isell_prod_view_db.sfdc_opportunity_lifecycle B    
            where B.oprty_key_nbr = '983yhjheksi9ru8jdl'
            and B.orl_adnr_amt is not null
             group by 1,2,3 ) B
             
on A.oprty_key_nbr = B.oprty_key_nbr

group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

Here are the results that I am getting:
|oprty_key_nbr......|Closed_Won_ADNR|OPEN_Phase_MIN_ADNR|#Changed_ADNR_Amts|
|-------------------|---------------|-------------------|------------------|
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |1900           |                   |2                 |
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |               |1900               |2                 |
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |               |1500               |2                 |

Here is what I WOULD LIKE to see:
|oprty_key_nbr.....|Closed_Won_ADNR|OPEN_Phase_MIN_ADNR|OPEN_Phase_MAX_ADNR|#Changed_ADNR_Amts|
|------------------|---------------|-------------------|-------------------|------------------|
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |1900           |1500               |1900               |2                 |

Here is my data:
|oprty_key_nbr......|orl_adnr_amt|orl_stage_phase_nm|
|-------------------|------------|------------------|
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |1900        |Closed - Won      |
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |1900        |Open Stage 4      |
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |1900        |Open Stage 4      |
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |1500        |Open Stage 4      |
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |1500        |Open Stage 4      |
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |1500        |Open Stage 4      |
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |1500        |Open Stage 3      |
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |1500        |Open Stage 2      |
|983yhjheksi9ru8jdl |?           |Open Stage 1      |

[Image of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwoVU.png)
Appreciate your help!

Comment: sorry, not sure why the tables are not showing correctly.  I've added an image.

Comment: If you only want 1 row per OPRTY_KEY_NBR then that should be the only column in the GROUP BY.  Maybe you can use MIN/MAX around the CASE and get one row per key in the "B" subquery, or maybe you need MIN/MAX added to the outer query. BTW - If tables are not displaying correctly, please post as plain text so data is legible (not image).

Comment: @Fred  Thanks Fred, I'll give it a try.  And thanks for the TIP!